# Are mutex locks necessary when modifying values?

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_map and I'm using mutex locks for emplace and delete, find operations, but I don't use a mutex when modifying map's elements, because I don't see any point. but I'm curious whether I'm wrong in this case.

Should I use one when modifying element value?

```
std::unordred_map<std::string, Connection> connections;

// Lock at Try_Emplace
connectionsMapMutex.lock();
auto [element, inserted] = connections.try_emplace(peer);
connectionsMapMutex.unlock();


// No locks here from now
auto& connection = element->second;
// Modifying Element
connection.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: when only a single thread accesses the element, no mutex is needed

Comment: Are you accessing the map from more than 1 thread? If not, there is no need for any mutex.

Comment: OTOH if any other threads might be concurrently inspecting or modifying the `unordered_map`, then all threads need to have the mutex locked during the time they inspect or modify it.  (otherwise, there is a chance that one thread will try to read the `unordered_map`'s state while another thread is halfway through changing that state, and the first thread will "see" inconsistent data and then Bad Things will happen)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Multiple threads.

Comment: As an additional note, you really should be using a `scoped_lock()` instead of manually locking and unlocking mutexes, lest you expose yourself to some nasty surprises.

Comment: @Frank I use lock_guard, but for example I went explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what can happen when you have one thread reading from the map and the other one writing to it:

1. Thread A starts executing the command `string myLocalStr = element->second.foo;`
2. As part of the above, the `std::string` copy-constructor starts executing:  it stores `foo`'s character-buffer-pointer into a register, and starts dereferencing it to copy out characters from the original string's buffer to `myLocalStr`'s buffer.
3. Just then, thread A's quantum expires, and thread B gains control of the CPU and executes the command `connection.foo = "some other string"`
4. Thread B's assignment-operator causes the `std::string` to deallocate its character-buffer and allocate a new one to hold the new string.
5. Thread A then starts running again, and continues executing the `std::string` copy-constructor from step 2, but now the pointer it is dereferencing to read in characters is no longer pointing at valid data, because Thread A deleted the buffer!   Poof, Undefined Behavior is invoked, resulting in a crash (if you're lucky) or insidious data corruption (if you're unlucky, in which case you'll be spending several weeks trying to figure out why your program's data gets randomly corrupted only about once a month).

And note that the above scenario is just on a single-core CPU; on a multicore system there are even more ways for unsynchronized accesses to go wrong, since the CPUs have to co-ordinate their local and shared memory-caches correctly, which they won't know to do if there is no synchronization code included.

To sum up:  Neither `std::unordered_map` nor `std::string` are designed for unsynchronized multithreaded access, and if you try to get away with it you're likely to regret it later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do, if and only if I'm threading and there's a chance other threads are manipulating the list and its contents.

I would create a mutex lock when manipulating the list (which you've done) or when traversing the list.

And if I felt it was necessary to protect an individual item in the list (you're calling methods on it), I'd give each one a distinct mutex. You could change element A and element B simultaneously and it's fine, but by using the local locks for each item, each is safe.

However, it's very rare I've had to be that careful.

Comment: If you lock for write then you also need to lock for read, otherwise a consumer may access the map while it is in the process of being modified.

Comment: If one thread modifies element A while another thread is searching the list and happens to look at the value of element A you’ve got a data race, hence, undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I rarely require separate read/write locks. That's more complexity than usually necessary outside of databases -- in my experience. So I just use a single lock.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, so the amount of locking you have to do is going to be based on your problem space.

Comment: @JosephLarson I don't mean you need a read lock, and a read/write lock. I mean that if you are creating a mutex lock when you manipulate the list, you also need to lock that mutex when you are reading that list.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah. I went back through my exact words and what you said and made a small adjustment.